# HTTP service not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, httpservice

**This is my HttpService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
   constructor (private http: Http) {}

    getData() {
        return this.http.get('http://blog_api.org/v1/posts')
            .map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }
}
```

**This is my app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from '../app/services/HttpService'
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `Hello`,
})
export class AppComponent  {
    constructor (private httpService: HttpService) {};

    ngOnInit() {
        this.httpService.getData()
            .subscribe(
                data => console.log(data)
            )
    }
}
```

**When I running app, I get error:**

> EXCEPTION: No provider for HttpService!

Comment: Always remember to Google the error message first. A query for `EXCEPTION: No provider for HttpService!` will turn up loads of existing questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must provide the `HttpService` in the model that loads the `app.component.ts`.

In your case, as you are using `app.component.ts`, provide the `http` in `app.module.ts`. Something like:

```
import { HttpService } from '../app/services/HttpService'

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ... 
    HttpService,
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your AppModule you should be doing:

```
import {HttpService} from "...";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [...],
    imports: [HttpModule],
    declarations: [...],
    entryComponents: [...],
    providers: [HttpService]
})
export default class AppModule{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

> providers: [HttpService]

in @Component block

Comment: If you du this you will end up with a lot of http instances. I think is better to load it at the top level module and ensure a single instance.